# Can a Serilog.ILogger be converted to a Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger?

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I have code that logs to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger (and extension methods, mostly).

I have configured Serilog to actually do the logging.

I can't find a way to convert a Serilog.ILogger to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.  I assumed that Serilog would be implementing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger, but it doesn't seem to.

Is there a way to get a Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger interface on the Serilog Logger??
--- Thanks

The code I have is:

```
        Serilog.Core.Logger seriLogger = new Serilog.LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();
        Serilog.ILogger seriILogger = seriLogger;

        Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger msLogger = seriILogger;
```

produces

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Serilog.ILogger' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

a cast gets me a runtime error:

Unable to cast object of type 'Serilog.Core.Logger' to type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger'

Answer (score 54):

Apart from installing `Serilog.AspNetCore` you could also install `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` and use these lines of code. This will give you some ideas how `UseSerilog()` works under the hood (well, more or less this way :D).

```cs
var serilogLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.Debug() // Serilog.Sinks.Debug
    .CreateLogger();

var microsoftLogger = new SerilogLoggerFactory(serilogLogger)
    .CreateLogger<IMyService>(); // creates an instance of ILogger<IMyService>
```

Or if you need to use the logger in the DI container use these lines of code:

```cs
Log.Logger = serilogLogger;

var container = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddLogging(x => x.AddSerilog())
    .BuildServiceProvider(true);
```

Comment: I like this because it is independent of all the ASPNET Core infrastructure, allows me to pass ILogger to libraries and remove dependency of Serilog from them.

Comment: In the .CreateLogger<IMyService>(), what is IMyService?

Comment: @Michael, I have added a command about it. It's a random service which is a generic type argument in `ILogger<T>`

Comment: @mihails.kuzmins Yours is the first suggestion I have seen that makes it this easy to get an instance of ILogger<IMyClass>, I wonder why that is?

This seems like a super usefull way to get an instance that can be used for passing into class constructors.

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR No, not directly. The compiler is correctly refusing to convert as the Serilog ILogger / Logger does not directly implement the MEL `ILogger` interface (The Serilog project started ~2012 and has always been designed to operate independent of any specific frameworks of that, or later times...)

There is however a bridging layer that implements the MEL `ILogger` interface, forwarding to the Serilog `ILogger` - [There's an intro article on this topic](https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/) which presents a good overview. Depending on your app type, you may not need all of that, but it should give you some context as to how it all fits together.

Comment: Perfect - that's just what I needed.  I thought it had been written to plug into the MEL.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this and register DI Serilog.ILogger to SerilogToMsLog

```
public class SerilogToMsLog: Serilog.ILogger
{
    private readonly ILogger<SerilogToMsLog> _logger;

    public SerilogToMsLog(ILogger<SerilogToMsLog> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Write(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        if (logEvent.Level == LogEventLevel.Error)
        {
            _logger.LogError(logEvent.Exception,logEvent.RenderMessage());
        }
        
    }
}
```